# Explain trigonometry rewrite

Tags: trigonometry

While looking at a solution to a longer task I found this part that confuses me. How is this rewrite done? As it is presented in a one step way it should be trivial but I can't see it.

$$ \left| \sin x \cosh y + i \cos x \sinh y \right|^2 = (\sin x \cosh y)^2 + (\cos x \sinh y )^2 $$

Could someone please explain how this is done? (and why you can remove the absolute markings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complex number $a+bi$, we have
$$
|a+ib|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\implies|a+ib|^2=a^2+b^2.
$$